# How to get Windows Server 2008 R2 File and Directory Permissions

Tags: ntfs, file-permissions

**I have a setup similar to this:**
e:\personal\username1\scans
e:\personal\username2\scans
e:\personal\username3\scans
e:\personal\username3\scans

Permissions are not inherited on these directories.

I have all permissions in place that I need, except that I need to add in username1 to have all rights **except** *"full control"* of *"username1"* and the *"scans"* directory below it.
 

I would like to use icacls.exe for this, can someone give me the correct syntax? If you can give me that much, I can do the rest of what I need.

Comment: I'd personally use the powershell command get-acl.

Answer (score 1):

cacls e:\personal\username1\scans /t /e /g **Users**:f

where **Users** is your user name for this particular folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sure seems like icacls -? would have given this to you:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: I asked for the syntax, as in an example because I looked at the /? for it, and cant get it to work correctly.